# Geometry Nodes: Transfering materials from Object to Instances in Blender 3.6

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I have a molecule object that I am creating instances of on a plane. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to match the materials of the instances as well. My current node set up is based on this post: [Geometry Nodes: Transfer materials to instances touching faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255845/geometry-nodes-transfer-materials-to-instances-touching-faces), but unfortunately it is not working, and I had to make some assumptions since the Transfer Attribute node is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Instances within Geometry Nodes can't be assigned different materials directly, but you can leverage attribute values to match them up in the material nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a try.